# What is the expected performance of a team in a contest?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients, expected-value

> Suppose $n$ people are competing in a contest. Among them is a team of $m$ people ($m < n$), performance of which is defined as the maximal rank achieved by any of its neighbours. What is the expected performance of the group if all participants are equally skilled?

The problem can be alternatively formulated as:

> Suppose $\sigma$ is a random permutation uniformly distributed on $Sym(\{1, ... , n\})$. What is $E[min\{\sigma(i)| i \leq m\}]$?

The probability of any given outcome is $\frac{1}{n!}$. For any $k \leq i \leq n$, the number of outcomes in which a given member of the team takes $k$-th place and everyone else in the team performs even worse is $C_{n-k}^{m-1}$. Thus the number of outcomes in which the performance of the team is $k$ equals to $m C_{n-k}^{m-1}$. So the expectation of the outcome is:

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-m} mC_{n-k}^{m-1}}{n!}$$

However, I wonder, if there is a closed form to this expression. I tried to simplify it anyhow, but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Hockey-stick formula, you get that
$$\sum _{k=1}^{n-m}mC_{n-k}^{m-1}=\sum _{k=m}^{n-1}mC_{k}^{m-1}=m(C_{n}^m-1).$$
Just a comment for the confused reader: $C_n^m=\binom{n}{m}.$